# Magento 2: difference between Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder and Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder?

Tags: magento2, search-criteria, service-contract

Those two classes are very similar but I don't get the differences and why should one be used instead of another ?

- `Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder` => a handful of references in the Magento native code.
- `Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder` => 200+ references

To me, there must be a good reason why the first one has been created but I don't get why.

Anyone can enlight me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They build different objects:

- `Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria`
- `Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteria` (which extends the former)

The `Search/SearchCriteria` has two additional methods:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getRequestName();

/**
 * @param string $requestName
 * @return $this
 */
public function setRequestName($requestName);
```

This request name is used by UI components to identify the search request. If I understand it correctly, the interfaces in `Api/Search` are meant for actual **searches** by the user, while the common `Api/SearchResults` and `Api/SearchCriteria` interfaces are used for any repositories (i.e. collection filtering and sorting)